# Moving and zooming map-layer while editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, zoom

I want to create lines with the help of "CAD-like improved line capture", make a point, pretend an angle or distance want to put the second point. To this end, I have to zoom out on the map, select a different part of the map and there zoom in again. Here, however, I lost the tool and the firt point/vertex ist lost.

Is there a way to prevent this?